# Creating a generic Iostream Class in Java

Tags: java, class, iostream

Basically, I need a "myIO" class, which requires the programmer to specify at the beginning what the input and output type are. I have no idea how to do this in Java, but in cpp, I would define a "toString" or "display" function inside of each class I made which converted the class object into something which can be displayed on a console or written to a file. Then I would overload the cout operator "<<", and use that with any ostream type variable. I am essentially not sure what the equivalent istream and ostream type variables are in Java. SO here is what I need essentially:

```
public class IOS<Tin, Tout>{
    private "istream" _inputSource;
    private "ostream" _outputSource;

    public IOS(Tin in, Tin out){
        _inputSource = new "istream"( (typecast if necessary) in );
        _outputSource = new "ostream"( (typecast if necessary) out);
    }

    public String read(){
        //code which reads in data somehow, in c++ I could use stringstreams or something similar
    }

    public void print(ObjectType Object){
        //code to somehow write any object to a file
    }

}
```

In the above code block, Tin and Tout are the types of the input variables. The format of this doesn't matter, I just don't know what types these need to be. The "istream" and "ostream" would be the type variables for the functions in c++, and I have no idea what they should be here. I basically need this class to be capable of reading in and writing any type of object to any type of file source. If this isn't possible, then I need it to do the latter at the least, and I can just overload it for each type.

If you have any good resources or thoughts on how to do this, please let me know. I am primarily a C/C++ coder, and am being forced to write this application in Java, so I'm kind of getting lost in the different syntax.

An example of how it would be used by an abstract class is:
    public class something_abstract(){
        private Type someKindOfVariable;
        IOS myIO = new IOS("istream" type object, "ostream" type object);
        public void display(){
           myIO.println(someKindOfVariable);//so this prints this to the specified ostream type object... this is the part I don't understand: what type is this ostream object, and how do I pass this into a user made class designed to handle any type of ostream and any type of object
        }

Thanks!

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you update it with some sample code of how you expect this IOS class to be used?

Comment: yes, so in a separate abstract class, it would look something like

    public void display(){
        IOS myIO = new IO("istream", "ostream");//these are variables of this type presumably which can specify the output/input methods
        myIO.println(something of type string);
}

Does that help? I am honestly not sure how this will be implemented, as I have no idea how the IOS class can be structured in Java

Comment: @crazygirl9991: That ought to be edited into the question, rather than posted as a comment.  It just looks like a jumble of crap down here.

Comment: sorry hold on, I never post on here, and I'm not sure how to do stuff properly.

Comment: Don't worry about implementation yet, first think about how your class is to be used. This is a good advice for *any* class class design, not just this one.

Answer (score 0):

Please read some basic syntax  of java first sample progarm to read a file from a location and 
write into another location

link to learn stream in java

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File originFile = new File("c:\\file1.txt");
    File destinationFile = new File("c:\\file1.txt");
    if (!originFile.exists() || destinationFile.exists()) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(originFile);
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
      int i = fis.read(readData);

      while (i != -1) {
        fos.write(readData, 0, i);
        i = fis.read(readData);
      }
      fis.close();
      fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to a type-specific iostream?

Comment: I already understand the code you have, and have reviewed the link, but there must be something that I am missing. This is just for file ios, correct? I need the method of ios to be of any type. As generic as possible. As in, the programmer could specify the input/output type as standard in or out, or a file, or some other method of interaction which I have as of yet not defined. Is FILE a generic type that can support this level of generics? I was under the impression that it could only be used for file ios. Also, the input and output need to be able to be separately specified.

Answer (score 0):

Java's analogues for `istream` and `ostream` are `java.io.InputStream` and `java.io.OutputStream`, respectively.  (Or `java.io.Reader` and `java.io.Writer`, if you're dealing with chars rather than bytes.)  There are subclasses that deal with files, sockets, etc, and subclasses like `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` to read and write bytes, ints, etc.  In Java, you chain the different types of streams together to get what you want.

In Java, you'd have something like

```
import java.io.*;

public class IOS<TIn, TOut> {
    private InputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    public IOS(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
        this.in = new DataInputStream(in);
        this.out = new DataOutputStream(out);
    }

    public TIn read() {
        // use this.in to read in bytes and assemble an object with them
    }

    public void write(TOut output) {
        // use this.out to write out bytes
    }
}
```

With all this said, though, you may not even need it.  Java has an `ObjectOutputStream` class that can write serializable objects out, and an `ObjectInputStream` that can read them in.  Pretty much all you have to do is implement `Serializable` correctly.  (This is a little harder than it sounds, but not outrageously so; basically, it means making sure that your persistable contents are serializable as well.)

Comment: do you have a good resource I can use to understand how to serialize my code? I learn best from reading good examples... I can try a google search (and will anyway) but you might have something better and more easily accessible...?

Comment: I don't have any on me...i picked it up from a Java book ages ago.  But implementing `Serializable` can be as simple as implementing the interface on your class (it's just a marker interface, so there's no functions to write), and using only serializable types within the class (or marking the non-serializable sub-objects as transient).  Lemme see if there's a simple example out there that's not broken all to hell.  :)

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm looks straightforward enough.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I would overload the cout operator "<<", and use that with any ostream type variable.

Java does not have operator overloading so this cannot be done.